# Getting correct data to show up from query and array

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I have a query I am doing and I want to loop through the query and then display those items on my html using smarty.

```
$results = $db->query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM `athlete_bio_youtube` WHERE `PersonID` = %d ORDER BY `athlete_bio_youtube`.`Date` DESC, `athlete_bio_youtube`.`Date` DESC;', $id));


foreach($results as $result) {
    $result['Link'];
    $result['Date'];
    $result['Title'];
}

$smarty->assign(value($params, 'to', 'video'), $result);
```

THIS CODE BELOW IS MY HTML..I want to take the three columns of link, data, and title from my controller. Put that information into my html.

```
{if $video.Date != ''}
{foreach $video as $results}
        {$results.Link} 
        {$results.Date} 
        {$results.Title}
        <br />
{/foreach}
{/if}
```

I am getting back this data on my html which is the first character of each piece of data that comes back from the query.

2 2 2 
6 6 6 
h h h 
0 0 0 
t t t

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it just me or your code is hard to understand (`foreach($results as $result) {` this loop seems hard to read)?

Comment: also it doesn't do anything. Why do you loop over $results? Looks like you are omitting code.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be something like:

```
    foreach($results as $new_variable) {
        $result['Link']=$new_variable['Link'];
        $result['Date']=$new_variable['Date'];
        $result['Time']=$new_variable['Title'];
    }
```